# How to find all file names in a directory using windows wildcards

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, wildcard, regex-negation

i have two files:

```
asdf.txt.txt
asdf.txt
```

Is it possible to use cmd to find only the file ending .txt and not the file above it: .txt.txt?

I have :

```
 dir *.txt
```

but it still yields both files

is it possible to do this

ps this is for a homework assignment but i looked on line and can't find any way to do this from the cmd line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I won't provide the full answer. But there is a simple solution that uses pipes (`|`) and FINDSTR.

Answer (score 2):

```
dir *.txt | findstr/v/i "txt.txt"
```

`findstr/v` will suppress the lines that contain "txt.txt".  `/i` tells it that the string in quotes is not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It depends on what you're trying to do.  Both files are technically *.txt.  You could do something like dir *f.txt or you could use some faux regex with findstr:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As dweiss pointed out, the result given to you is technically correct.

Another (albeit perhaps more complex) solution is to use [Powershell to perform GREP-like commands](http://dereknewton.com/2010/12/powershell-grep-equivalent).

Answer (score -4):

Starting with:

thing.txt
thing.txt.txt

REN *.txt.txt *.xyz

thing.txt
thing.txt.xyz

DIR *.txt

lists only thing.txt

DIR *.xyz

lists only thing.txt.xyz

REN *.xyz *.txt

gives you back the original filenames.